# Mongodb query performance extremly bad with $or

Tags: mongodb, performance, count

I use MongoDB 3.2.13 and I have a collection C with about 500K documents. The documents contain a String field A which can only a handful of different values. If I query the collection for specific values like

```
db.getCollection('C').count({'A':{'$eq': 'valueA'}}) 
db.getCollection('C').count({'A':{'$eq': 'valueB'}})
```

I get results in under **1 second**.
If i do a combined search using $or

```
 db.getCollection('C').count({'$or':
       [
       {'A':{'$eq': 'valueA'}},
        {'A':{'$eq': 'valueB'}}
       ]
 })
```

the query runs about **165 seconds**.
I have an index an A. I can't explain why the $or query is so much slower? This is just a simple example that could be solved by just adding the results of the first two queries but we have other queries that can not easily be split up.

Can anyone explain what is wrong the $or query? Or give me a hint how to speed it up?

db.getCollection('C').find(query).explain() gives:

```
 {
     "queryPlanner" : {
         "plannerVersion" : 1,
         "namespace" : "db.C",
         "indexFilterSet" : false,
         "parsedQuery" : {
             "$or" : [ 
                 {
                     "A" : {
                         "$eq" : "valueA"
                     }
                 }, 
                 {
                     "A" : {
                         "$eq" : "valueB"
                     }
                 }
             ]
         },
         "winningPlan" : {
             "stage" : "SUBPLAN",
             "inputStage" : {
                 "stage" : "FETCH",
                 "inputStage" : {
                     "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                     "keyPattern" : {
                         "A" : 1
                     },
                     "indexName" : "A",
                     "isMultiKey" : false,
                     "isUnique" : false,
                     "isSparse" : true,
                     "isPartial" : false,
                     "indexVersion" : 1,
                     "direction" : "forward",
                     "indexBounds" : {
                         "A" : [ 
                             "[\"valueA\", \"valueA\"]", 
                             "[\"valueB\", \"valueB\"]"
                         ]
                     }
                 }
             }
         },
         "rejectedPlans" : []
     },
     "executionStats" : {
         "executionSuccess" : true,
         "nReturned" : 2513596,
         "executionTimeMillis" : 133764,
         "totalKeysExamined" : 2513597,
         "totalDocsExamined" : 2513596,
         "executionStages" : {
             "stage" : "SUBPLAN",
             "nReturned" : 2513596,
             "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 131660,
             "works" : 2513597,
             "advanced" : 2513596,
             "needTime" : 0,
             "needYield" : 0,
             "saveState" : 20912,
             "restoreState" : 20912,
             "isEOF" : 1,
             "invalidates" : 0,
             "inputStage" : {
                 "stage" : "FETCH",
                 "nReturned" : 2513596,
                 "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 131490,
                 "works" : 2513597,
                 "advanced" : 2513596,
                 "needTime" : 0,
                 "needYield" : 0,
                 "saveState" : 20912,
                 "restoreState" : 20912,
                 "isEOF" : 1,
                 "invalidates" : 0,
                 "docsExamined" : 2513596,
                 "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                 "inputStage" : {
                     "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                     "nReturned" : 2513596,
                     "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 4420,
                     "works" : 2513597,
                     "advanced" : 2513596,
                     "needTime" : 0,
                     "needYield" : 0,
                     "saveState" : 20912,
                     "restoreState" : 20912,
                     "isEOF" : 1,
                     "invalidates" : 0,
                     "keyPattern" : {
                         "A" : 1
                     },
                     "indexName" : "A_1",
                     "isMultiKey" : false,
                     "isUnique" : false,
                     "isSparse" : true,
                     "isPartial" : false,
                     "indexVersion" : 1,
                     "direction" : "forward",
                     "indexBounds" : {
                         "A" : [ 
                             "[\"valueA\", \"valueA\"]", 
                             "[\"valueB\", \"valueB\"]"
                         ]
                     },
                     "keysExamined" : 2513597,
                     "dupsTested" : 0,
                     "dupsDropped" : 0,
                     "seenInvalidated" : 0
                 }
             }
         },
         "allPlansExecution" : []
     },
     "serverInfo" : {
         "host" : "xxxx",
         "port" : 27017,
         "version" : "3.2.13",
         "gitVersion" : "23899209cad60aaafe114f6aea6cb83025ff51bc"
     },
     "ok" : 1.0
 }
```

Comment: Where is the index on the `"A"` property? There really should be one with 500K documents. How about running `db.getCollection('C').find(query).explain()` both before and after `db.getCollection('C').createIndex({ "A": 1 })`

Comment: Added the answer to explain to the question. The interesting thing is the count without **$or** is 1 Second. The count with **$or** is 160 Seconds and the find with **$or** is 16 Seconds. Why the differences?

Comment: Sorry for not being explicit. `.explain(true)` so it would at least give some indication of the millseconds taken for the query plan execution.

Comment: added new explain result

Comment: You used sparse index on "A". Any specific reason? If not then can you drop the sparse index and create normal index and try running same query. I am still not sure on this but feels something to sparse.

Comment: No specific reason. I dropped and recreated the index as not sparse. No change in find or count times.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$in` instead of `$or` ([Mongo $or vs $in docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or-versus-in)):

```
db.getCollection('C').count({'A':{'$in': ['valueA', 'valueB']}})
```

### `UPDATE`

Or try with a find(..).count() like this:

```
db.getCollection('C').find({'A':{'$in': ['valueA', 'valueB']}}).count()
```

Comment: that makes little to no difference :(

Comment: and again. no difference. somehow I think the problem lies elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

After searching and searching i found the reason. One of the values i was search for had null values. Null is not covered by the index so every document was read from disk to check if is ha null or not.

It's also mentioned in the Mongo University Workshops. I can strongly recommend taking the classes. They helped me a lot!